# "Deceptive site ahead" issue with my Laravel app

Tags: web-hosting, security, shared-hosting, deployment

I developed a Laravel app using Laravel. After deployment, every time I try to access the app, it says "Deceptive site ahead".

I tried searching for fixes and doing almost everything that I found but still failed to fix it. I submitted a report to Google already and there's no response yet. And yes, this app asks for specific information such as full name, email, country, and phone number. This bothers me and keeps me from proceeding to phase 2 of the project. I used Livewire and a Bootstrap template for development. I don't know if this is a code issue, a config issue, or it is just the domain.

I tried searching for fixes, and even submitted a request for review to Google, but there's no response yet. APP_DEBUG is set to false. Fixed the src already using `asset('resources_here')`.

To be honest I have no idea what the exact issue is. Here's my htaccess. My Laravel app is placed in public_html folder using A2hosting's shared hosting package.

DirectoryIndex public/index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ https://mysitesamp.com/public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Maybe its simply because you don't have a security certificate

Comment: Already configured the SSL cert. It even says HTTPS at first. Now the domain is gone. It redirects me to a page which says "This domain is for sale".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can do anything, you need to find out what specifically is causing the error. Set up Google Search Console for your site so you can view the [Security Issues report](https://search.google.com/search-console/security-issues):

[image: "security & Manual Actions" > "Security issues" > "6 issues detected", ranging from "Hacked: URL injection" to "Unclear mobile billing"]

(Image source: [How to Fix the Deceptive Site Ahead Google Warning](https://www.wpexplorer.com/deceptive-site-ahead-warning/))

If you already have GSC set up, make sure there are no unauthorized users.

The report will list what problems your site has, on what pages, and give you an idea of how to fix it. The problems will either be:

- In your code (I hope that you're not trying to do social engineering, though it can also be caused by something more innocuous like failing to correctly label third party services)
- In content that you're loading, such as advertisements
- In code that was added to your site by hackers, which will often try to hide. (And finding the security hole is its own rabbit hole — Is your hosting secure? Are there any vulnerabilities in your Composer dependencies? Is the code that you wrote secure?)

Once you are sure that the issues are resolved (or you know they are false alarms) you can submit a report to Google.

See also the [Google Search Central page for the "Deceptive site ahead" warning](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/monitor-debug/security/social-engineering).

Comment: Thanks. I did the same exact thing and it said "deceptive pages". I didn't do anything though other than fixing the labels and I sent a request for review on Google. They reviewed the contents, and I got a positive response. The site is now working.